# Count the number of answer types selected in a survey using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, survey

I need to track/count the answers that users select for an online survey.

The survey has 18 questions and each question has two answers (which can be 1 of 4 colours).

Based on my beginner level of javascript, the way I'm thinking of achieving this is to basically have the questions generated in a `<ul>` and have the two answers inside the `<li>` tags.

I'll create an event listener that adds a class, say `.selected`, to the answer that's picked (but also removes it from the sibling element to ensure only one is ever selected), and then when the user hits submit, I'll tally up the results (using something like `.map()`) of the colours selected by counting them in an array with a key-value pair for each colour. The key with the highest count will be the result.

I've tried to search for a codepen for this seemingly simple problem but I haven't been able to find anything specific enough. Does anyone have any suggestions?

[image: Question answer types]

I found an example of a survey that uses answers on a scale of 1-5. There are only two answers and each one would correspond to certain colours. The HTML is relatively basic:

```html
<div class="container text-center">
    <ul id="quiz" class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item prompt">
            <p>I often make spontaneous or last-minute decisions</p>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                <div class="btn-group"><button class="value-btn btn btn-default btn-agree">Agree</button></div>
                <div class="btn-group"><button class="value-btn btn btn-default btn-disagree">Disagree</button></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item prompt">
            <p>My ideas are often unconventional or radical</p>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                <div class="btn-group"><button class="value-btn btn btn-default btn-agree">Agree</button></div>
                <div class="btn-group"><button class="value-btn btn btn-default btn-disagree">Disagree</button></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item prompt">
            <p>I am naturally inclined to step forward and lead the group</p>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                <div class="btn-group"><button class="value-btn btn btn-default btn-agree">Agree</button></div>
                <div class="btn-group"><button class="value-btn btn btn-default btn-disagree">Disagree</button></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item prompt">
            <p>I make decisions based on logic and am rarely swayed by emotions</p>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                <div class="btn-group"><button class="value-btn btn btn-default btn-agree">Agree</button></div>
                <div class="btn-group"><button class="value-btn btn btn-default btn-disagree">Disagree</button></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But the JS is where I'm really having troubles with. I current have this code that activates the button that has been selected and will also deactivate the other button in the div accordingly, but it only saves for the first question...:

```js
document.querySelector('.value-btn').onmousedown = function showSelection() {
    const classList = $(this).attr('class');
    const classArr = classList.split(" ");
    const this_group = classArr[0];

    // If button is already selected, de-select it when clicked
    // Otherwise, de-select any selected buttons in group and select the one just clicked
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.'+this_group).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
};
```

Next, finally, I need to figure out how I can count the answers selected. I could use `data-attributes` to add a colour to each agree and disagree button manually, but how do I count the selected buttons?

Here's what I have right now in a codepen: https://codepen.io/mance-rah/pen/xxgaeQL

I'm also open to completely scrapping my current approach for a cleaner, easier way to solve this.

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right track, but StackOverflow works best when you show us your actual code that you have attempted to write, so that we can give you feedback on what you have written. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67167959/edit) to show us the code you have written so far, even if it is not complete or working.

Comment: Yeah you're absolutely right. I just spent the last hour adjusting code and adding it to a codepen. I've added it to my question.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67167959/edit) to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code. Including a link to an external site like Codepen as well is fine, but it should not be the sole location of your code, since external sites can change or disappear over time, making your question difficult to understand.

Comment: I've made some additional changes and created minimal, reproducible code. Is this better?

Comment: Instead of making the answers to each question consist of two buttons, I would use a radio group. Not only can you use CSS to style them to look like buttons, but the fact that they are a radio group means the browser will only allow one of them to be selected, without requiring you to add JS click handlers. As for tallying up which colors were selected, I like your idea of using data attributes. You can probably count them easily like this, e.g. `var numRed = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-color="red"]').length` (where the red buttons are `<input type="radio" data-color="red" ...>`).